# C# converting strings to int's

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and am trying to make a simple calculator.
It works fine until it goes back to the start to take a new number.
When taking the new number it says it cant convert the user input to a integer.

```
using System;

namespace simpleCalculator
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            start:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first number");
            int x = Convert.ToConsole.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to\n1. Add\n2. Multiply\n3. Devide");
            string o = Console.ReadLine();
            if (o == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter second number\n");
                int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                add(temp, y);
                goto start;



                Console.Clear();
                goto start;
            }
        }
        public static void add(int num01, int num02)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine((num01 + num02) + "\nPress enter to contiue.");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you say exactly which line gives you the error?

Comment: Have you looked at int.TryParse?

Comment: try using while(true) instead of goto and use tryparse. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What's Convert.ToConsole.ReadLine()?

Seems like that's where your problem is to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for int.Parse(). Be careful to validate your input. You should probably create an escape condition.

**Edited to show an alternative solution**
**Edited to be more explicit on how to handle some input**

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = String.Empty;
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter first number");
                 x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to\n1. Add\n2. Multiply\n3. Divide");
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a second number");
                y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                continue;
            }
            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine($"{x} + {y} = " + add(x, y));
                    break;
                case "2":
                    //TODO implement multiply case
                    break;
                case "3":
                    //TODO implement divide case
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static int add(int x, int y) => x + y;
}
```

Comment: Which will still error with:  Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: That line as it stands does not have an error. It is meant as an example that OP can use to fix his issue.

Comment: Unfortunately as freedom states, your solution will still crash as the OP's does. So it really isn't a solution.

Comment: "Be careful to validate your input."

Comment: I've been more explicit now.

Comment: "Be careful to validate your input" `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` does **not validate** the input and in fact causes the same error as the original.   As stated, enter something other than a number.  It's the number part, *not* the operation part that's in question, you've expanded on the operation, but left the numbers as failing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TryParse` so if the parsing fails, you will not get an exception.

```
var enteredValue = Console.ReadLine();
var parsedValue;
if (!int.TryParse(enteredValue, out parsedValue))
{
    // parse failed do whatever you want
}
```

Do that for both entries and if both of them pass, then call your `add` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`int numbers = Convert.ToInt32("1234");`